# How to integrate admob interstitial in asynctask or in non-ui thread android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, admob

I have tow Activities Splash Screen And Main Activity. I want to integrate Admob interstitial in non- ui thread between splash Screen And Main Activity. After Splash Screen progress dialog show "please wait" and after some few second admob interstitial shown. like android asynctask
when we close admob interstitial then Main Activity Shown. like shown in figure
[image]

how i integrate Admob like that?
any help will be appreciated
thanks in advance

Comment: check if interstitial shown is not run then not call in main activity.. add this condition ,when you call main activity.

Comment: i use android asynctask for admob but unfortunitly stop working

Comment: no it is not right way to show admob..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This flow will not work for you.

It often takes 20-30 seconds for interstitial ad to be retrieved, so it is highly unlikely that an interstitial ad will be available for showing immediately after your splash screen.

You need to consider another point in your app at which it makes sense to show interstitials. NB not all apps are suited for this type of advertising.

Answer (score 0):

With info in your question, I guess it's NetworkOnMainThreadException. If it is the case, run it on Ui thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                           //Your code to show ad here
                        }
                    });
```